# Is the sequence $(x_n)$ convergent in the space $L_1(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Is the sequence $(x_n)$ convergent in the space $L^1(0,1)$ ?
>
> $x_n(t)= n^2 t^n (1-t^2)$  for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> norm: $\|x\|=\int_{(0,1)} \left|x(t)\right| \;  dt$

I think it should converge to zero, by checking the graph. but I cannot show it explicitly.

Could you please help?

Comment: Have you tried using dominated convergence? As far as i can see, this will give you the desired convergence directly.

Comment: Note $x_n\ge0$ and $(x_n)$ converges pointwise to the zero function. You can compute the required integrals explicitly, and easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\left| (x_n)(t) \right|$ converges pointwise to the $0$ function on $[0,1]$.
- We have
  \begin{align*}
  \left\|{x_n}\right\|
  &= \int_0^1 \left(n^2 t^n - n^2 t^{n+2}\right) \; dt \\
  &= \frac{n^2}{n+1} - \frac{n^2}{n + 3} \\
  &= \frac{2n^2}{(n+1)(n+3)} \to 2 \\
  \end{align*}

Since $L^1$ convergence implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere for some subsequence, the only candidate for $x_n$ to converge to in the $L^1$ norm is the zero function.  But $\left\|{x_n - 0}\right\| \to 2 \ne 0$, so $x_n$ does not converge to any function in the $L^1$ norm.

---

**Direct proof that $L^1$ convergence implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere for some subsequence:**

Let $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$.
Then for any $k$, let $E_{n,k}$ be the set of points where $\left|f_n - f\right| > \frac{1}{k}$.
Note that $\left\|{f_n - f}\right\|_{1} \ge \frac{1}{k} \mu(E_{n,k})$,
implying that for a fixed $k$, $\mu(E_{n,k}) \to 0$.

For each $i$, choose an integer $n_i$ so that $n_i$ is an increasing sequence of integers, and $\mu(E_{n_i, i}) < \frac{1}{2^i}$.
Note that this means $\mu(E_{n_i, k}) < \frac{1}{2^i}$ whenver $k \le i$.

Now consider the set $E$ of points $x$ where $f_{n_i}(x) \not \to f(x)$.
We have
$f_{n_i}(x) \not \to f(x)$ if and only if there is some $k$ such that $\left|f_{n_i}(x) - f(x) \right| > \frac1k$ infinitely often.
Therefore,
$$
E = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{i=N}^\infty E_{n_i,k}
$$
So
\begin{align*}
\mu(E)
&\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=N}^\infty \mu(E_{n_i,k}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{N \to \infty \atop N \ge k} \sum_{i=N}^\infty \mu(E_{n_i,k}) \\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{N \to \infty \atop N \ge k} \sum_{i=N}^\infty \mu(E_{n_i,i}) \quad \quad (\text{since } k \le i) \\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{N \to \infty \atop N \ge k} \sum_{i=N}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{i}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (0) = 0\\
\end{align*}

Therefore, $f_{n_i} \to f$ pointwise outside the set $E$ of measure $0$.

---

In fact, the above proof used the fact that $f_n \to f$ *in measure*, which is a weaker (more general) condition than convergence in $L^1$ norm.  For an extended discussion of this fact (Corollary 3, Exercise 6) and others, see [Terry Tao's blog post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence).
See also [this more recent mathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/750492/68107).

Comment: thanks. could you please explain the part: "$L^1$ convergence implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere"

Comment: @user104078 I didn't type that quite right; I meant $L^1$ convergence implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere *for some subsequence*.

Comment: @user104078 I've added a proof of that fact (which was stated incorrectly before).  Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

$\{f_n\}$ does  not converge in the $L^1$ sense.

Observation I. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx=2.$

Observation II. For every $0<a<1$, the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ in $[0,a]$.

So, due to II, for every $a\in(0,1)$, there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$, such that for $n\ge n_0$:
$$
\int_a^{1}f_n(x)\,dx>3/2 \quad\text{and}\quad \int_0^a f_n(x)\,dx<1/2.
$$
Then, due to I, we can find an $m>n$, such that $f_m(x)<1/2$, for $x\in[0,a_n]$, and thus $\int_{a_n}^1 f_m(x)\,dx>3/2$.
Thus
$$
\int_0^1 \lvert f_m-f_n\rvert\,dx\ge\int_{a_n}^1 \lvert f_m-f_n\rvert\,dx\ge \int_{a_n}^1 f_m-\int_{a_n}^1 f_n\ge \frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=1.
$$

Comment: "For every $n$, there exists an $a_n < 1$, such that $\int_0^{a_n} f_n(x) \; dx > 3/2$" is false.  For $n = 1$, we have $\int_0^1 f_1 = \int_0^1 t(1 - t^2) \; dt = \frac14$, so no subinterval has an integral bigger than $1/4$.

Comment: @Goos: Correct. I have made the appropriate changes.